# Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have encountered an issue when i tried to run "ng serve -o" to run the angular application an error messages appears "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema"

Before, the angular "ng serve -o" is working, but when i installed "npm install ngx-bootstrap --save" ,"ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component datepicker" and "npm install webpack --save-dev" this command "ng serve -o" is not working now.

**Here is the screenshot of the error**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CV45.jpg
[image]

Anyone can help me to figure out this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error was likely caused by installing Webpack:

```
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

The Angular CLI already has it's own Webpack dependency, which is how it builds and serves the app. Adding Webpack to your project likely crosses wires with the internal configuration in the CLI.

Try uninstalling Webpack and see if you can serve the app again.

```
npm uninstall webpack

ng serve -o
```

Comment: Hi @Dale Harris, Thank you for your help.

When i tried to uninstall webpack and re-run 
"ng serve -o" ,
I still get an error "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema"

Here is the screenshot:
https://imgur.com/yK4VIh0

Thank you so much

Comment: @NekZurc Unfortunately it'll probably take some trial and error. I would try these commands next: Remove Webpack from dependencies: `npm uninstall webpack --save-dev`; Clean the NPM cache: `npm cache clean`; Reinstall your packages: `npm install`; Try to serve the app again: `ng serve -o`

Comment: Thank you so much @Dalle for your help, it works fine now when i tried to re install "npm install"